# How can I get the MKMarkerAnnotationView image?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mkannotationview

I have created a map image using the MKMapSnapshotter.  Unfortunately the snapshotter does not let you add annotations so I would like to add my annotation directly onto the view.

I know for a pin you can do the following get the UIImage of the pin:

```
let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: nil, reuseIdentifier: nil)
let pinImage = pinView.image
```

This works fine.  However I want the image of the marker.  I have tried the following but unfortunately nothing appears.

```
let markerView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: nil, reuseIdentifier: nil)
let markerImage = markerView.image
```

I have changed image to glyphImage and no difference.  Is there anyway to get the marker image?